# AFNetworking 3.0 - How to post headers?

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

I'm very new for Objective-C programming. I am living a problem and not solving it.

I have a Web Service and it response to me some key/value when I sent headers via Postman as in the screenshot below. I must post request and it must response to me according to my sent headers. But when I tried in Xcode with Objective-C using AFNetworking 3.0, I saw "nil" in responseObject although request succeed.

My codes are as below.

I'm waiting for your help.

[Postman Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ulwB.png)
[xCode result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aB78a.png)

```
-(void)postData {
static NSString * const baseURLString = @"https://yonetim.ozmanoto.com/Uretim/DataTransfer.aspx/MusterileriGetir"; 
NSDictionary *params = @{@"method":@"MusterileriGetir",@"name":@""};

AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [[AFHTTPSessionManager alloc]initWithSessionConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];
manager.requestSerializer = [AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer];
[manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"method" forHTTPHeaderField:@"MusterileriGetir"];
[manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"name" forHTTPHeaderField:@""];

manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];

[manager POST:baseURLString parameters:params progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"success! %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {
    NSLog(@"error: %@", error);
}];
```

Comment: Does the script designed to respond anything? Is it a SOAP request instead of a HTTP request?

Comment: @Raptor Yes, It designed to respond. When I sent "name" to be empty value, it responds me first 50 object from service.

Answer (score 0):

You are override your own manager that have `requestSerializer` with new manager in this line `manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];`, it probably override your request header setting

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your header and body value similar? if you have not need body parameter then pass `parameters:nil` Might be help following code!

```
[manager POST:baseURLString parameters:nil progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"success! %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {
    NSLog(@"error: %@", error);
}];
```